# Are there any other way to get latitude and longitude of user except Network provider and GPS provider?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have to get latitude and longitude of user but not using GPS Provider and Network Provider.
I am building android application and I have to get latitude and longitude of user without GPS Provider and Network Provider.

I’m expecting to get latitude and longitude through nearby Network towers.